# How to use the patch decorator to patch a method instead of using it with context manager

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have the following Python unit test case.

```
import json
import rules
from rules import RULES
import models
from django.test import TestCase
from mock import patch

class RulesTest(TestCase):

    request_length = 484
    url = "http://www.ndtv.com"

    def setUp(self):
        har_data = open('/Users/rokumar/SiteAnalysisGit/Src/hct/exportfiles/test.har')
        self.data = json.load(har_data)
        self.rule = models.Rule(name=RULES.DNS,user=None,
            threshold=None)
        self.rule.save()

    def tearDown(self):
        self.rule.delete()

    def test_parse_har(self):
        with patch.object(rules, 'add_dns_analysis', return_value=None) as \
        dns_mock: 
            dns_mock.add_dns_analysis('test result', 'test url')
            result = rules.parse_har(self.data,[self.rule],RulesTest.url)
            self.assertEqual(result[RULES.TOTAL_REQUESTS], 484)
```

Can I mock the add_dns_analysis method using @patch decorator instead of context manager and when should I use either of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case you can use either decorator and context and even `patch` instead of `patch.object`. For instance your test could be rewrite as

```
@patch.object(rules, 'add_dns_analysis', return_value=None)
def test_parse_har(self,dns_mock):
    dns_mock.add_dns_analysis('test result', 'test url')
    result = rules.parse_har(self.data,[self.rule],RulesTest.url)
    self.assertEqual(result[RULES.TOTAL_REQUESTS], 484)
```

or

```
@patch('rules.add_dns_analysis', return_value=None)
def test_parse_har(self,dns_mock):
    dns_mock.add_dns_analysis('test result', 'test url')
    result = rules.parse_har(self.data,[self.rule],RulesTest.url)
    self.assertEqual(result[RULES.TOTAL_REQUESTS], 484)
```

**EDIT**
I wrote that answer by thing the question was *When to use...* instead of *How to use...*. So the next part is about *When to use the patch decorator to patch a method instead of using it with context manager*.

But in general by decorator you can obtain cleaner code than the context version. For instance if need to patch more object the decorator version looks like

```
@patch('amodule.A.a_method')
@patch('amodule.A.b_method')
@patch('amodule.B.c_method')
def test_mytest(self,bc_mock,ab_mock,aa_mock):
    ...
```

but the context version looks like:

```
@patch('amodule.A.a_method')
@patch('amodule.A.b_method')
@patch('amodule.B.c_method')
def test_mytest(self):
    with patch('amodule.A.a_method') as aa_mock:
        with patch('amodule.A.b_method') as ab_mock:
            with patch('amodule.B.c_method') as bc_mock:
                ....
```

I think that in that case decorator's version is real better.

`patch` decorator is powerful but not a silver bullet. For instance if in your test you need configure something in your patch that depend from other object or your class you can't use decorator:

```
def mytest(self):
    foo = Foo()
    with patch('amodule.A.a_method', return_value=self.a_return, my_property=foo) as m:
        ...
```

The last example where you have to use `with` instead of `patch` is when you need more one patch of the same object in the same test or you need both patched and unpatched version:

```
 def mytest(self):
    with patch('amodule.A.a_method', return_value="first") as m:
         ....
    with patch('amodule.A.a_method', return_value="second") as m:
         ....
    amodule.A.a_method() #original
```

Finally you can obtain a complete fine grain by a direct use of `enter()` `exit()` methods of the `patch` object but I think that is a little bit out of scope in that answer.

Comment: Nicely explained. Thanks.

Comment: @user567797 Just to understand. Why you have not upvoted it if you found it useful and so "That answer give some contribute to the post". I apologize for my question but I'm relative new to SO and I'm trying to understand the rules and dynamics.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you could use @patch decorator. In my opinion, there is no big difference between both decisions.

Comment: But how to use @patch decorator on methods. It can be used on classes and attributes.

Comment: Тhere is example: http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/patch.html#patch-object